# Postgres function returns table parameter name used more than once - slight twist

Tags: postgresql

I've read the other similar questions where input and output params are named the same.  Simply renaming a param, and using a type are common solutions to these problems.  In my case I'm trying to use our existing ORM code (c# in this case) to map the output, and the mapping models cannot be changed.

```
CREATE TABLE parent (parentid integer, statuscode text);
CREATE TABLE child (childid integer, parentid integer, statuscode text);

insert into parent (parentid, statuscode) values (1, 'enabled');
insert into child (childid, parentid, statuscode) values (1, 1, 'enabled');
insert into child (childid, parentid, statuscode) values (2, 1, 'disabled');
```

My c# model classes look like

```
class Parent {
   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   public string StatusCode { get; set; }
   public List<Child> Children {get;set;}
}

class Child {
   public int ChildId { get; set; }
   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   public string StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

I can write this query in pgadmin and dump it to the screen and it shows both columns named statuscode:

```
select p.parentid, p.statuscode, c.childid, c.statuscode 
from parent p 
inner join child c on c.parentid = p.parentid;
```

Obviously I cannot dump that into a pg function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.parent_child_join(parentid integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(parentid integer, statuscode text, childid integer, statuscode text)
    LANGUAGE 'sql'

AS $BODY$
select p.parentid, p.statuscode, c.childid, c.statuscode 
from parent p 
inner join child c on c.parentid = parent_child_join.parentid;
$BODY$;
```

without the error ERROR:  parameter name "statuscode" used more than once
SQL state: 42P13

I have more experience with SQL Server where such a stored proc is possible.

There are some easy code work-arounds, such as make different data models and map to end model, or possibly skip the function and just supply the raw sql statement.

Any other suggested work-arounds that aren't as hack-ish?
Is pgadmin using relative position to access the resultset, hence duplicate column names?

Comment: Hmm, so c# tag is removed, yet I'm probably stuck fixing it in c#.  Odd edit choice, there.  To boot, I just saw some c# suggestion to add attributes to alter my mapper.

Comment: The error message is coming from PostgreSQL because it can't return multiple colums with the same name from a function. Once you fix that, then you can use attributes to map properties to those unique column names. But you need to fix the PostgreSQL function, first.

Comment: Name the output table columns `p_statuscode` and `c_statuscode` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  These are some both obvious solutions that were explored per the question stated above.  I was hoping there was some more eloquent solution.  I may just alias the output column and use either an intermediate map, or use attributes to redirect the existing mapper.  Seems odd that there are some system level functions with input and output params named the same, but user defined ones cannot.

Comment: I wonder how something like Babelfish would handle this use case.  https://babelfish-for-postgresql.github.io/babelfish-for-postgresql/